# How to get last crash log from ArchLInux

Tags: arch-linux, logs, crash

My system suddenly crashed, I have restart it, where could I find the last/previous crash log, since there are no `/var/log/syslog*` anymore..

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
journalctl --since=today
```

[Reference](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journalctl.html)

Comment: or journalctl --since="2021-03-18 00:17"

Answer (score 27):

To get the log of the last boot, execute as root or with `sudo`:

```
journalctl -b -1
```

learned from [this discussion](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=189948).